# Configuring bottom bar in QLPreviewController

Tags: ios6, ios7, uitoolbar, uidocumentinteraction, qlpreviewcontroller

I have integrated QLPreviewController and UIDocumentInteractionController in my app, and it is working fine.

The only problem is- I want to configure the bottom toolbar, I want to remove the default toolbar items, which appear as shown in image below:

[image: Bottom tool-bar with items to be removed]

Is there any way to do so, please suggest.

Comment: set the toolbar to nil and call setneedsdisplay

Comment: Did you get any solution for this? Not working in iOS 7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short Answer: **NO, Not in IOS6+**

Description:

One thing to note about QLPreviewController is that it's not meant to be customized.  There were other libraries allowing you to change the functionality such as:

```
https://github.com/rob-brown/RBFilePreviewer
```

**Which are not working in iOS 6+** since apple made a big change in QLPreviewController and it's technically running in a separate process. Although it might be possible (not sure) using private apis but your app will be rejected then.

You can find more info about this change here:
http://oleb.net/blog/2012/10/remote-view-controllers-in-ios-6/

Hope this helps

Comment: Just thinking how whatsapp guys might have configured it? I mean they show a small 'delete icon' in bottom right and 'All Media Files' on top, which in default preview controller case appears at bottom right.

Comment: @Miraaj they might have their own viewer. not sure. also look at iOS8 stuff there might be something new in this regard

Answer (score 2):

1. Subclass [UIToolbar](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIToolbar_Class/)
2. Create `UINavigationController` using 
   [init(navigationBarClass:toolbarClass:)](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationController_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UINavigationController/initWithNavigationBarClass:toolbarClass:) and supply `UIToolbar subsclass` created in step 1 for `toolbarClass`
3. Create `QLPreviewController` instance and push onto UINavigationController stack
4. Inside of `UIToolbar subsclass` override 
   [setItems(_:animated:)](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIToolbar_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIToolbar/setItems:animated:). To remove all buttons call super with empty array `super.setItems([], animated: false)` or potentially you can add only buttons you want to keep.
5. Present `UINavigationController` created in step 2

Here is the example [PreviewControllerHideBottomButtons](https://github.com/mruvim/PreviewControllerHideBottomButtons)

Answer (score 0):

- Subclass QLPreviewController.
- Search for the Toolbar in the view hierarchy.
- Have a UIToolbar property in your class that has the same frame as the original toolbar.
- Place your own toolbar above the default one with whatever buttons you want.
- If you want it to be hidden as the default behavior of the QLPreviewController you can key value observe the hidden property of the default toolbar and present / hide your own accordingly.